# The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. Laravel 5.5 Production

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-5.5

I am trying to submit login page so i can access . It is in production stage. in localhost it works perfectly, but online when hosted it brings this error

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

my login page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<!-- begin login -->
        <div class="login bg-black animated fadeInDown">
            <!-- begin brand -->
            <div class="login-header">
                <div class="brand">
                    <!-- <span class="logo"></span> Color Admin -->
                    AGPAHI
                    <small>Reporting Portal</small>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end brand -->
            <div class="login-content">
                    {{--  <img src="{{ asset('img/AGPAHI.png') }}"><br/>  --}}

                <form class="margin-bottom-0" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg inverse-mode no-border" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus/>

                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg inverse-mode no-border" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />

                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox m-b-20">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-buttons">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Login</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                            Forgot Your Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end login -->
@endsection
```

what i have done:
1) added the csrf token inside the form
2) changed writing permission on the storage path

what may be the problem?

Comment: Check the session cookie you're getting on the login page and make sure the one you send with the form submission is the same. If it's not then you might have some strange paths or hosts set on your cookie settings.

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks for the heads up on that, didn't realise that was the output!

Answer (score -1):

You can change `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to `{{ csrf_field() }}`
And, after this run commands 
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan config:cache`